# Python: Splitting a string into words, saving separators

Tags: python

I have a string:

```
'Specified, if char, else 10 (default).'
```

I want to split it into two tuples

```
words=('Specified', 'if', 'char', 'else', '10', 'default')

separators=(',', ' ', ',', ' ', ' (', ').')
```

Does anyone have a quick solution of this?

PS: this symbol `'-'` is a word separator, not part of the word

Comment: Could you give us a complete set of separator characters? Currently, we know `[' ', ',', '(', ').']`. Are there more? Or should perhaps every character which is *not* alphanumeric be considered a separator? You need to be more specific.

Comment: In addition to the questions Tomas asked, is there a reason that parentheses are grouped with spaces, but commas are not?

Comment: I've rewritten regex for me now it uses non-alphanumeric characters as a separator `^[a-Z0-9]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import re
line = 'Specified, if char, else 10 (default).'
words = re.split(r'\)?[, .]\(?', line)
# words = ['Specified', '', 'if', 'char', '', 'else', '10', 'default', '']
separators = re.findall(r'\)?[, .]\(?', line)
# separators = [',', ' ', ' ', ',', ' ', ' ', ' (', ').']
```

If you really want tuples pass the results in [`tuple()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#tuple), if you do not want `words` to have the empty entries (from between the commas and spaces), use the following:

```
words = [x for x in re.split(r'\)?[, .]\(?', line) if x]
```

or

```
words = tuple(x for x in re.split(r'\)?[, .]\(?', line) if x)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex for that.

```
>>> a='Specified, if char, else 10 (default).'
>>> from re import split
>>> split(",? ?\(?\)?\.?",a)
['Specified', 'if', 'char', 'else', '10', 'default', '']
```

But in this solution you should write that pattern yourself. If you want to use that tuple, you should convert it contents to regex pattern for that in this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Regex to find all separators (assumed anything that's not alpha numeric

```
import re
re.findall('[^\w]', string)
```

Answer (score 0):

I probably would first `.split()` on spaces into a list, then iterate through the list, using a regex to check for a character after the word boundary.

```
import re
s = 'Specified, if char, else 10 (default).'
w = s.split()
seperators = []
finalwords = []
for word in words:
    match = re.search(r'(\w+)\b(.*)', word)
    sep = '' if match is None else match.group(2)
    finalwords.append(match.group(1))
    seperators.append(sep)
```

Answer (score 0):

In pass to get both separators and words you could use findall as follows:

```
import re
line = 'Specified, if char, else 10 (default).'
words = []
seps = []
for w,s in re.findall("(\w*)([), .(]+)", line):
   words.append(w)
   seps.append(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my crack at it:

```
>>> p = re.compile(r'(\)? *[,.]? *\(?)')
>>> tmp = p.split('Specified, char, else 10 (default).')
>>> words = tmp[::2]
>>> separators = tmp[1::2]
>>> print words
['Specified', 'char', 'else', '10', 'default', '']
>>> print separators
[', ', ', ', ' ', ' (', ').']
```

The only problem is you can have a `''` at the end or the beginning of `words` if there is a separator at the beginning/end of the sentence without anything before/after it. However, that is easily checked for and eliminated.